# Good workflow for uploading thousands of files

Tags: shell, ftp, sftp

Every day ~30000 files are created on one server and then they should all be moved to a  web server. Until now I've been using `ncftpput` for transferring all the files but it's very slow and stops now and then.

My plan now is to gzip all the files and then use `scp` to transfer the archive to my web server and then unpack it there.

Is this a good solution or is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use "rsync" if available on your platform. It is restartable, only does the minimum necessary and very fast and easy to use.

Comment: Additionally rsync has the added advantage of doing the compression for you using the -z flag. Using rsync you can avoid gziping and unpacking afterwards

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better than upload raw files.
But I found this: Slow Upload Speeds via SCP - https://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-134902.html